# What kind of timezone is TimeOfDay in TimeZoneInfo AdjustmentRule

Tags: c#, timezone, dst

I see that there are start and end date of daylight transition. There's a property called TimeOfDay. It displays something like 1/1/0001 2:00:00 AM. I want to know what time is this refer to? Which country, which timezone? or it is UTC? Can anyone explain?

so, is the time given there the local time of computer? or the local time of country using 'Mid-Atlantic Standard Time'? or UTC? sorry it might be a stupid question but I am new to timezone

More info: This is the code I use to query : 
*(copied up from a comment below for clarity)*

```
System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mid-Atlantic Standard Time")
   .GetAdjustmentRules().Dump();
```

Comment: The UTC time is equal to the local time minus the UTC offset. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getutcoffset(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Where do you see this property? I can't see it in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule.aspx).

Comment: I can't find any reference but I'd be fairly sure it was the time for that timezone at that time.

Comment: More info: This is the code I use to query : System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mid-Atlantic Standard Time").GetAdjustmentRules().Dump();

Comment: @Oded: `System.TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime` object is returned by `DaylightTransitionStart` and `DaylightTransitionStart` properties and this has the TimeOfDay on it. Documentation for it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.transitiontime.timeofday) seems sadly lacking in specifics.

Comment: so, is the time given there the local time of computer? or the local time of country using 'Mid-Atlantic Standard Time'? or UTC? sorry it might be a stupid question but I am new to timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the relevant class for UK time by using the following command:

```
System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time").GetAdjustmentRules().Dump();
```

And knowing that we go forward from 1AM to 2AM instantaneously nad from 2AM to 1AM when going the other way I can say that the TimeOfDay for the GMT one matches up with the local time taking into account daylight saving. ie the 1AM start is GMT with no modifiers. The 2AM finish is GMT+1 for summertime.

This is only an anecdotal answer but it definitely works for this timezone and I would imagine it works for others too.